# Hide a field each time an input from a specified form is changed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to hide #result each time an input in #my_form is changed. I tried this but it doesn't work

```
$('#my_form .input').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(ev) {
    $('#result').hide();
  });
});
```

EDIT : I have another button that shows #result

EDIT 2 : It works with that but it doesn't work for select_tag

Even if I do this :

```
$('#my_form input').on('input | change | keyup | keydown | select', function(){
  $("#result").hide();
})
```

Comment: Try to remove `.`: `$('#my_form input')` instead of `$('#my_form .input')` (unless they have a class called `input`)

Comment: Makes little sense, since it will hide `#result` after the first change, and you never show it again. Can you post HTML?

Comment: What do you want then? Exactly when to hide and when to show?

Comment: Thanks it works ! Can you put it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('#my_form .input').on('input,change,keyup,keydown,', function(){
  $("#result").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it's a little more gentle on the DOM

```
// get the result element once    
var result = $('#result');
// declare a method to handle the input change once, not every time the event happens
function input_changeHandler(event) {
    result.hide();
}
// bind the listener to your form (using more efficient selectors)
$('#my_form').on('change,keyup', 'input, select, textarea', input_changeHandler);
```

Just be careful of scope, as 'result' would be global. If you wrap it all in a method (closure), you'd be fine.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can some thing like this

```
$(".input").on("input", function() {
    alert("Value changed!");
    $("#result").hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dobg9huu/)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, if you are looking to attach to the `input` elements, you shouldn't put a dot in front of it, as that will look for elements with *class* input.

Also you don't need to loop through and apply the changes to each `input` individually. You can just bind it on the initial selector.

Lastly, [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) is the recommended way to add event handlers in jQuery since v1.7

```
$('#my_form input').on('change', function() {
  $('#result').hide();
});
```

If you want to hide it when any key is pressed etc, rather than just when the input loses focus, you can attach multiple event handlers, but they should be separated by a *space*, not any other character (see previous link to on documentation):

```
$('#my_form input').on('input change keyup keydown', function() {
  $('#result').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok everything above works for some things but what I find works even with select_tags :

```
$('#simulation :input').on('input | change | select', function(){
  $("#result").hide();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Why using the **$.each** function while you can handle the event like this:

```js
$('#my_form .input').on('input | change | keyup | keydown', function(){
  $("#result").hide();
})
```

use $.on() better and use 'input' HTML5 event that fires whene a field is changed and also 'change, keyup, keydown' to be sure that the event fires if the browser not supporting input event, also 'change' event has some bugs, it don't fire in all cases, but 'input' event fires perfecty for any type of user behavior (like ctrl+v, mouse right click > past, or even mouse wheel for number input)

Comment: Hi, politely I want to ask that the code fulfills the need, what is the reason for downvote? It captures the input, change, keyup and keydown events to hide the result

Comment: Maybe it's because you let .input (the class) instead of telling that  I should use "input" instead of ".input" :)

Comment: Hahaha, read the first comment on your question that puts this point that "if you have a class called input". Since no objection was bought forward hence assumption was made that you have a class input..

Comment: I thought that he have an .input class for his inputs, since not all form element have the <input> tag ...